# How to switch destination mail address by selecting check box in Laravel contact form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is contact form and sorking.

I would like to switch email destination by User selecting check box.

For example. Here is a column called `genders`.

When user check 'man' select box, email destination will be [TO]'man_survey@12345677.site' and [CC] is 'man_cc_survey@12345677.site'.

When user check 'female', email destination will be [TO] 'female_survey@12345677.site' and [CC] is 'female_cc_survey@12345677.site'

Could you teach me how to add this function to my current code?

My Laravel framework is 5.7.28

```
    public function complete(ContactRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->except('action');

        if ($request->action === 'back') {
            return redirect()->action('ContactsController@index')->withInput($input);        }


        if (isset($request->type)) {
            $request->merge(['type' => implode(', ', $request->type)]);
        }


        // store data
        Contact::create($request->all());

        // send mail
        \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
            'to' => $request->email,
            'to_name' => $request->name,
            'from' => 'survey@12345677.site',
            'from_name' => 'from name',
            'subject' => 'Thank you',
            'type' => $request->type,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'body' => $request->body
        ]));

        // recive mail
        \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
            'to' => 'survey@12345677.site',
            'to_name' => 'to name',
            'from' => $request->email,
            'from_name' => $request->name,
            'subject' => 'you got mail',
            'type' => $request->type,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'body' => $request->body
        ], 'from'));


        return view('contacts.complete');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** THis worked

public function complete(ContactRequest $request)
        {
            $input = $request->except('action');

```
        if ($request->action === 'back') {
            return redirect()->action('ContactsController@index')->withInput($input);        }


        if (isset($request->type)) {
            $request->merge(['type' => implode(', ', $request->type)]);
        }


        // store data
        Contact::create($request->all());


    if($request->gender == 'male') {

 // send mail

            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $request->email,
                'to_name' => $request->name,
                'from' => 'man_survey@12345677.site',
                'from_name' => 'from name',
                'subject' => 'Thank you',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ]));

            // recive mail
            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $email,
                'to_name' => 'to name',
                'from' => $request->email,
                'from_name' => $request->name,
                'subject' => 'you got mail',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ], 'from'));


            return view('contacts.complete');      


    } else {          

 // send mail
            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $request->email,
                'to_name' => $request->name,
                'from' => 'female_survey@12345677.site',
                'from_name' => 'from name',
                'subject' => 'Thank you',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ]));

            // recive mail
            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $email,
                'to_name' => 'to name',
                'from' => $request->email,
                'from_name' => $request->name,
                'subject' => 'you got mail',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ], 'from'));


            return view('contacts.complete');

    }


        }
```

Comment: Dear @marc_s Thank you very much for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a radio button in the form to see what Gender the user has selected.
In HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="no_answer">Prefer Not to Answer
```

In the controller you can use something like this

```
    public function complete(ContactRequest $request)
        {
            $input = $request->except('action');

            if ($request->action === 'back') {
                return redirect()->action('ContactsController@index')->withInput($input);        }


            if (isset($request->type)) {
                $request->merge(['type' => implode(', ', $request->type)]);
            }


            // store data
            Contact::create($request->all());


    if($request->gender == 'male') {
      $email = 'man_survey@12345677.site';
      $cc_email = 'man_cc_survey@12345677.site'
    } else {
        $email = 'female_survey@12345677.site';
        $cc_email = 'female_cc_survey@12345677.site'
    }

            // send mail
            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $request->email,
                'to_name' => $request->name,
                'from' => 'survey@12345677.site',
                'from_name' => 'from name',
                'subject' => 'Thank you',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ]));

            // recive mail
            \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
                'to' => $email,
                'to_name' => 'to name',
                'from' => $request->email,
                'from_name' => $request->name,
                'subject' => 'you got mail',
                'type' => $request->type,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'body' => $request->body
            ], 'from'));


            return view('contacts.complete');
        }
```

Comment: Dear @Abid Suleman Ahmed Thank you for answering me. May I have time to try your code out. Currently I have anohter problem this project so I can't try out your code.Please give me some time. after I As soon as fix this problem, I will contact you.

Comment: Dear @Abid Suleman Ahmed Thank you for waiting. I tryed your code. but Email wasn't sent. I used this gentlemans code. This is github page. You might figure out the reason  https://github.com/k-ishiwata/LaravelSimpleCMS/tree/fefa683bbd02106ab845fcf01d4ecf3f1f153076  and I have one more favor. I would like to add 3rd selection that is "Prefer not to answer"  and I would like to make switch function. not if and else.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the email server. Are you receiving the correct value in $email variable?

Comment: You can also check by hardcoding the email address in the 'to' key

Comment: Dear @Abid Suleman Ahmed. It worked as hardcording. I update my current code. Thank you. but somehow CC doesn't work. and  May I ask if I use, male, female, Prefer not to answer, these 3 select. What would you write code?

Comment: After seeing your updated code, you were getting the correct value in the gender variable. Then the other solution should work as well. I checked my code, I seemed to have missed a semi-colon after $cc_mail; perhaps that was the problem. I would recommend you to try the correct approach again as hardcoding is a way around, not a correct way

Comment: @greeniron You can make another radio button with the value 'no_answer' and you can apply your logic in the controller accordingly to that option, as you have done with male and female